# CSS top not working

Tags: html, css

i have this code html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>e-Rario</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 60px; background: blue;">
        <div style="top: 25%; background: green;">e-Rario</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the top property nor working?

Comment: add a position property to the div

Answer (score 1):

[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top), `bottom`, `left`, `right` and other properties (i.e. `z-index`) only work on `position`ed elements. A.k.a. having a set `position`, other than `static` (default).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>e-Rario</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 60px; background: blue;">
        <div style="top: 25%; background: green; position:relative;">e-Rario</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever you discover some simple css property *does not work* make sure you read the documentation provided by either MDN (more user friendly, open source joined effort of Mozilla, Google, Microsoft and many others) or W3C (more technical, but the authority for HTML & CSS standards) for it. Chances are you will find the answer there, much faster than it would take you to ask it here.
(Re)search on SO is not optional. You must do it and you must specify it in your question, when you have done it.